Alternate for google Instance ID service's batchImport method
Currently in my project  front-end (ios) is sending APNS token to backend and we(Backend) is doing the APNs token registration in firebase using google API's Instance ID service's batchImport method to map APNS token with a valid firebase token. But now is throwing Authentication error as its deprecated recently. Is there any alternative for this. I have seen alternate implementation from frontend(ios) side but I want to know if there is any alternate in backend itself 
Here is the documentation that we are currently following - https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens
